# Typescript Constructor Parameter Factory Typing

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-typings

I have classes whose constructors require objects which form a tagged union:

```
interface Info {
  x: string;
}

interface AInfo extends Info {
  x: 'a';
}

class A {
  constructor(info: AInfo) {}
}

interface BInfo extends Info {
  x: 'b';
}

class B {
  constructor(info: BInfo) {}
}

type AllInfos = AInfo|BInfo;
```

I've omitted class internals and constructor initialization. How can I type this factory function to correlate the type of object created based on the info passed in?

```
const factory = (info: AllInfos) => {
  switch (info.x) {
    case 'a': return new A(info);
    case 'b': return new B(info);
    // ...
  }
};

const obj = factory(myInfo); // type of obj is A|B, I'd like it to vary by myInfo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do it is by using overloads:

```
function factory(info: AInfo): A
function factory(info: BInfo): B
function factory(info: AllInfos) {
  switch (info.x) {
    case 'a': return new A(info);
    case 'b': return new B(info);
    // ...
  }
};

const objA = factory({ x: 'a' }); // A
const objB = factory({ x: 'b' }); // B
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIhge2QbwFDLIAeAXMgM5hSgDmA3HgL556iSyIoCC6WyERSCAAm5NBmz5CpZAHI4shszwIANnHJiuuAsgSYQlKAFcEYTFAAUoLGR4SAlLmbK20eEmQAhXtgFDRcT4pYjJZACNFJhY1DTEvHUJ9QypTcysbTDIfR2dovDAATwAHblVVXzEAXmR7LAAfHKwGPBhjEDNgA2QPdMLrCTtfBztW9s7u3ot+zOzh7LGOsC6QHsQ+gdta8sqnEPIAd2AwBAALZE3MADoiPd0kjRR5WTIoCDBjKFWQCAPay4cDEID3IT0ir3en2+v28AKBwIA9AjkFdUboXC1kpRkJhwgArbQ1KZQfo4UJyBTIRiA5BI2oqAzY3F4hJE9bTSxkmQRWRUml0rxAA)

If there are a lot of options in the union, you can get creative and create a distributive conditional type to create a signature for each member in the union, and then make it into an overloaded signature using `UnionToIntersection` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50374908/125734)):

```
type UnionToIntersection<U> = 
  (U extends any ? (k: U)=>void : never) extends ((k: infer I)=>void) ? I : never

type Factory<T> = T extends new (p: infer P) => infer R ? (a: P) => R : never
type FactoryParameters<T> = T extends new (p: infer P) => infer R  ? P : never
type AllClasses = typeof A | typeof B

const factory = ((info: FactoryParameters<AllClasses>) => {
  switch (info.x) {
    case 'a': return new A(info);
    case 'b': return new B(info);
  }
}) as UnionToIntersection<Factory<AllClasses>>;

const objA = factory({ x: 'a' }); // A
const objB = factory({ x: 'b' }); // B
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)